# Python, rethinkDB: progress of multiple inserts not displayed

Tags: python, python-2.7, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am inserting roughly 10k documents from a CSV file into a rethinkDB table; the code looks like this

```
print "inserting records",
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        document = # do some stuff to create the document
        insert_record(document)
        print ".",
```

As you can see after each insert a dot should be printed on screen to show the progress of the operation.
Unfortunately what I see instead is:

1. nothing happens for a few seconds
2. the "inserting records" and a large number of dots is shown all at once
3. nothing happens for a few seconds
4. again a number of dots is shown all at once
5. 3 - 4 repeat until all docuemnts are inserted

Why are the print commands "cached" and then done in batches and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not an answer to the question but something to consider: RethinkDB supports bulk inserts: [RethinkDB FAQ](http://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/answers-to-common-questions/#can-rethinkdb-do-bulk-inserts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when printing to stdout, the output will be buffered and then flushed when it grows large enough.  Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print statement, and the output should be smoother.